# class template with nullptr-function-ptr argument

Tags: c++, templates

I did not find any results on this but only on different problems.
So in my case I have a function-pointer as a template Parameter. The class is built up like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, T> class Callee;

// specialization for full types 
template <typename TObject, typename... TParams, typename TReturn, TReturn (TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
class Callee<TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function>
{
  public:
    Callee( TObject& instance ) : instance_{instance}
    {
    }

    TReturn call(TParams... data) 
    {
        return (instance_.*Function)(std::forward<TParams>(data)...);
    }
  private:
    /** the used instance */
    TObject& instance_;
};
```

It's just a snippet, call() is normaly derived from a pure virtual method so it can be called from other instances via the interface and just imagine all the other specializations for voids etc. that shouldn't matter for the subject.
It has a small creator:

```cpp
// declaration
template <typename T> class CalleeCreator;

// primary template
template <typename T> 
class CalleeCreator
{
}
// specialization
template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams> class CalleeCreator<TReturn(TParams...)>
{
    template <typename TObject, void (TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
    static Callee<void (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function> *createCallee(ConstCharPtr name, TObject& instance)
    {
        return new Callee<void (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function>(instance);
    }
}
```

We would instantiate it like this:

```cpp
class FuncClass
{
  public:
   uint32_t func(uint32_t);
}
FuncClass funcClass;
// drop returnValue for example
createCallee<uint32_t(uint32_t)>::createCallee<FuncClass, &FuncClass::func>(funcClass);
```

like I said there is an interface-class which is not shown here which enables other instances to call this callee.
anyway in rare cases it is possible that I need to create a callee which's calls are just unimplemented (so that a non-existent callee is indeed always existing as a dummy so you can't call a nullptr but the call in the end ends in emptiness).

For that I want a specialization of Callee for nullptr as a function pointer. Is that possible?

My try was

```cpp
template <typename TObject, typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
class Callee<TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), nullptr>
{
  public:
    Callee() = default;

    TReturn call(TParams... data) 
    {
        return TReturn{};
    }
};
```

But of course I get a reasonable error when only trying to create the template first:

```
error: non-type template argument specializes a template parameter with dependent type 'T' class Callee<TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), nullptr>

note: template parameter is declared here 
template <typename T, T> class Callee;
                      ~^
```

As I learned you cannot overload class template declarations. Is there a possible solution?

Thanks!

Comment: As you have interface, how about create another class `template <typename Sig> class NullCallee`?

Comment: Do you know about `auto` template parameters from C++17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is not directly possible per [`[temp.class.spec]/8.1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec#8.1):

> The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization.
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T, T t> struct C {};
> template <class T> struct C<T, 1>;       // error>
>
> template< int X, int (*array_ptr)[X] > class A {};
> int array[5];
> template< int X > class A<X,&array> { }; // error
> ```
>
> —end example ]

This is not that you cannot partially specialize a template with `nullptr`, function pointer or not, this is due to the type of that non-type parameter must not depend on another.

---

A possible solution would be to add an additional parameter to the base template. This can be as simple as a bool, it can be a type (à la `std::true_type`)...

```
template <typename T, T func, bool = (func == nullptr)>
struct Callee;

template <typename TObject, typename... TParams, typename TReturn, TReturn (TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
struct Callee<TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function, false>
{
    operator bool() const { return false; }
};

template <typename TObject, typename... TParams, typename TReturn, TReturn (TObject::*Function)(TParams...)>
struct Callee<TReturn (TObject::*)(TParams...), Function, true>
{
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};


#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    struct S { void f(){} } s;
    auto c1 = Callee<decltype(&S::f), &S::f>{};
    auto c2 = Callee<decltype(&S::f), nullptr>{};
    std::cout << bool(c1) << '\n'  // 0
              << bool(c2) << '\n'; // 1
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PzWaYKE1K)

Comment: This is a nice clean solution that is "under the hood" and does not affect any user-interface. thank you!